# iPhone: can i have a solution for converting NSNumber into NSString

Tags: iphone

hi i am working for Twitter client,  i want display number(NSNumber) on UILabel like follower count, tweet, friends counts etc

this is delegate to store user Profile Data in NSArray it contains all info like user name and screen name and no. of followers, messages, status count, following this detail i have to display on respective Labels

```
- (void)userInfoReceived:(NSArray *)userInfo 
              forRequest:(NSString *)connectionIdentifier    
{
NSLog(@"User Info Received: %@", userInfo);    
NSMutableDictionary *profileData = [userInfo objectAtIndex:0];
                             // userInfo is converted into NSDictionary
lblUserName.text = [profileData objectForKey:@"name"];
                             // user name is displaying on lblUserName UILabel
```

and here `lblUserName` - `UILabel`, `profileData` - `NSDictionary`, `userInfo` - `NSArray`

**On UILabel i have to display user follower count no**

how i have to work with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `stringWithFormat` which [behaves similar to printf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf). That is, you can pass a string with placeholders that are interpolated.

```
NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:100];
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d followers", [number intValue]];
NSLog(@"%@", string); // Would print "100 followers\n"
```

Comment: hi i want to print the Count(no. of follow) in UILabel which is stored in NSDictionary, please give me simple example

Comment: What are the keys and values in the dictionary? Assuming you have a key that is `@"fcount"` and a value that is a NSNumber which represents the number of followers you could do `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d followers", [[profileData objectForKey:@"fcount"] intValue]];`

Comment: hi Tate Johnson, this is method which convert NSNumber into NSString and print on UILabel   lblFriendsCount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [[profileData objectForKey:@"friends_count"] intValue]]; and here lblFriendsCount is UILabel and ProfileData is array, Friend_count is term used to search in array, thank you Tate Johnson, i got with you answer only, thank you one more time, have a great day

Answer (score 3):

`[NSNumber stringValue]` is good

Answer (score 0):

You should use [NSString stringWithFormat]

Answer (score 0):

NSNumber has an instance method called **integerValue**, which can convert an NSNumber object into a NSInteger. Then you can use NSString's **stringWithFormat** to convert that NSInteger into an autoreleased NSString.